# Scalatest or Specs2 - Set up and teardown of variables in tests running in parallel

Tags: scala, tdd, bdd, scalatest, specs2

If I have some variables that I need set up for EACH TEST IN A SUITE, is it possible to somehow set them up and get them into the test without writing a suite for each test?

I.e., setup:

```
val actorRef = context.actorOf(Props(new MyTestDude))
```

Teardown:

```
actorRef ! PoisonPill
```

If I run with setup and teardown hooks I need to have the actorref as a field in the test class so it's accessible from the setup method but then I can't run the tests parallel as everyone will share the same state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Scalatest, all of the Suite subclasses have some way of handling this, which is described in detail in the Scaladoc for the particular suite class.

Here is an example using FunSuite, based on the documentation. http://www.artima.com/docs-scalatest-2.0.M5b/#org.scalatest.FunSuite

```
class ExampleSuite extends fixture.FunSuite {

  case class F(actorRef: ActorRef)
  type FixtureParam = F

  def withFixture(test: OneArgTest) {

    val actorRef = context.actorOf(Props(new MyTestDude))
    val fixture = F(actorRef)

    try {
      withFixture(test.toNoArgTest(fixture)) // "loan" the fixture to the test
    }
    finally {
      actorRef ! PoisonPill
    }
  }

  test("My actor rules!") { f =>
    f.actorRef ! "very important message"
    assert( ... )
  }
}
```

Also note that Akka has a special module for ScalaTest called TestKit that will make testing actors in general much easier. http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/testing.html

Comment: Perfect thanks a tonne. I started reading Testing in Scala but you still got me to the answer faster than reading. Appreciate your time and direction.

Comment: It's described in the docs as well but the code above utilizes the loan pattern in fixtures for anyone curious about the cleanup tactics in isolation: https://wiki.scala-lang.org/display/SYGN/Loan

Answer (score 3):

For your information you can do something similar in specs2 by using the `AroundOutside` [implicit context](http://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/org.specs2.guide.Structure.html#Implicit+context):

```
import org.specs2._
import execute._
import specification._

class s extends mutable.Specification {
  // this context will be used for each example
  implicit def withActor = new AroundOutside[ActorRef] { 

    // actor is passed to each example
    val actor = context.actorOf(Props(new MyTestDude)) 
    def outside = actor

    // execute the example code
    def around[R : AsResult](r: =>R) = {
      try AsResult(r)
      finally (actor ! PoisonPill)
    }
  }

  "My actor rules!" in { actor: ActorRef =>
     actor ! "very important message"
     ok
  }
}
```